# DataLabels on series with many points

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I often have to show serieses with many points and I want to set dataLabels for some points. This works fine, but when the series has too many points, the dataLabel is not visible in the beginning. When I zoom into the series, I can see that it is displayed correctly.

So my question: Is there a way to show the dataLabel always for such a series?

Here is my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Charissima/9aB6B/
dataLabel at 51.

```
    $(function() {

        var myData = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            myData.push(i + Math.random() * 3);
        }
        myData.push(51);
        for (var i = 52; i < 400; i++) {
            myData.push(i + Math.random() * 3);
        }           

        chart = $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
            chart : {
                zoomType: 'x',
                events : {
                    load : function() {
                        myChart = this;
                        mySeries = this.series[1];
                    },
                }
            },

            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    formatter: setDataLabels
                    }
                }
            },

            series: [
                {
                    name: 'Label51',
                    id : 'dataseries',
                    color: 'blue',
                    data: myData
                }
            ]   

        });


        function setDataLabels() {
            if (this.y == 51) {
                return this.y;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }

    });
```

Comment: Well, your example works fine for me.. it's displaying dataLabel at 51. However, this may be caused by [`dataGrouping`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataGrouping.enabled). Try to disable it and we will see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by [`dataGoruping`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataGrouping.enabled) - disable it and will work fine.